# Sending specific variables from pipeline to Cloudwatch AWS

Tags: logging, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch, event-log

I try to send some variable values from my pipeline to the cloudwatch. My pipeline running on external linux machine.But that machine has got connection to reach AWS side.I use many times for s3 and other services.
My goal that in the last stage of my pipeline I try to send that specific variable values to the cloudwatch as a log.When I check with echo I can able to see values on pipeline output but I also send them to cloudwatch.How can I do that?

```
send-logs:
    stage: send-logs
    image: sample_v1
    script: 
        - echo "This is my first variable  ${alpha}"
        - echo "This is my second variable ${beta}"
```